# What are some good examples of processes to automate for a python beginner to start with?

Tags: python, linux, command-line

Trying to get some initial bearings on useful processes that a basic working knowledge of python can assist with or make less tedious. Specifically, processes that can be executed on the command line in a Linux environment. An example or two of both the tedious process as well as sample code to use as a starting point would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to automate depends on what you are doing manually and what your role is ? If you are a system administrator (say) and if you have shell scripts written to automate some of the tasks (like server management, user account creation etc.) you can port them to Python.

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, any suggestions for hobbyist scripts with utility for a casual user that a python learner could tweak?